# Combine two Worksheet_Change Subs

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need two actions to take place on one sheet in my workbook. Both are based on a change event, but do not know how to make them both work. Below is the codes that I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

    If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Don't change header color

    If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" Then
        r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Else
        r.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

And this one:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim r As Range
Set r = Target.EntireRow

    If Target.row = 1 Then Exit Sub ' Don't change header color

    If r.Cells(1, "E").Value = "6" Then
        r.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        r.Font.ColorIndex = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

To help determine the best course of action, here is what the end results must be:

For any row that has a date entered into cell AD, the text color for the entire row should change to green. However, if cell E of any row contains a 6 (this is a number formatted as text), then the text in that row should be red.

I am sure that I am over thinking this. All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `And` in your first `If` statement, and add an `ElseIf` statements.

I am not exactly sure what you want to take precedence if both a date and 6 exist or if there is one without the other, but you can easily adjust the `If Then ElseIf` block below to sort out your needs.

```
If r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" And r.cells(1,"E").Value = "6" Then
    r.Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf r.Cells(1,"AD").Value <> "" Then 
    r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
Else
    r.Font.ColorIndex = 1
End If
```

Comment: This helped a lot. However, I had to make a couple of small tweaks for it to work as needed. I removed 'r.Cells(1, "AD").Value <> "" And' from the first line and also changed the "6" to just 6. I did fail to mention in my OP what should take precedence, I apologize for that.

Comment: @IronMan - I suspected that just having the structure you need would take you home :) Glad you got it worked out.